# Foreach Articels from XML (image+Price)

Tags: php, html, xml

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kODMG.jpg)In this case, i am getting the first image of every Article, but only the same price for all Articles, see the screenshot.
i want to display every product image with the relevant price under.
i am using array unique to remove images duplications, which i believe that it is wrong.
i am getting data from xml.

```xml
<PRODUCTDATA>
    <PRODUCT>
        <P_NAME>
            <VALUE>Lether Jacket</VALUE>
        </P_NAME>
        <ARTICLEDATA>
            <ARTICLE>
                <A_PRICEDATA>
                    <A_PRICE>
                        <A_VK>34.95</A_VK>
                    </A_PRICE>
                </A_PRICEDATA>
                <A_MEDIADATA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://1.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://2.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://3.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://4.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                </A_MEDIADATA>
            </ARTICLE>
            <ARTICLE>
                <A_PRICEDATA>
                    <A_PRICE>
                        <A_VK>40.95</A_VK>
                    </A_PRICE>
                </A_PRICEDATA>
                <A_MEDIADATA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://11.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://22.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://33.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://44.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                </A_MEDIADATA>
            </ARTICLE>
        </ARTICLEDATA>
    </PRODUCT>
    <PRODUCT>
        <P_NAME>
            <VALUE>Jeans</VALUE>
        </P_NAME>
        <ARTICLEDATA>  
            <ARTICLE>
                <A_PRICEDATA>
                    <A_PRICE>
                        <A_VK>29.95</A_VK>
                    </A_PRICE>
                </A_PRICEDATA>
                <A_MEDIADATA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://111.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://222.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://333.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://444.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                </A_MEDIADATA>
            </ARTICLE>
            <ARTICLE>
                <A_PRICEDATA>
                    <A_PRICE>
                        <A_VK>19.95</A_VK>
                    </A_PRICE>
                </A_PRICEDATA>
                <A_MEDIADATA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://1111.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://2222.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://3333.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                    <A_MEDIA>https://4444.jpg</A_MEDIA>
                </A_MEDIADATA>
            </ARTICLE>
        </ARTICLEDATA>
    </PRODUCT>
</PRODUCTDATA>
```

```php
$xml = simplexml_load_file($datei);
    foreach($xml->PRODUCTDATA->PRODUCT as $p)
    {
        $prod = (string) $p->P_NAME->VALUE;
        $articles = "";
        foreach ($p->ARTICLEDATA->ARTICLE as $article)
        {
            $price = (string)$article->A_PRICEDATA->A_PRICE->A_VK;
            $firstImage = (string)$article->A_MEDIADATA->A_MEDIA;
            $articles++;
        }
    }
$articles .= '<div class="photo"><img src="' . $firstImage . '" style="width: 120px margin:5px;"><div class="product-info mt__15"><h3 class="product-title pr fs__14 mg__0 fwm">' . $prod . '</h3><span class="price">€' . $price . ' EUR</span></div></div>';
```

as $p is defined before as a Parent element in XMl as Product with many Articles inside.
The Variable $articlesss will then be inserted in a php long string that contain the full HTML page, so this is why i am trying to get them together in this variable.

Comment: What do you mean by _first price_? There is only one price.

Comment: I'm surprised you get a display at all. Because you set `$prices[$m]` as array, but you concatenate `">€' . $prices . ' EUR<`. This should give an _array to string_ error.

Comment: i am getting the first image of every Article, but only the same price for all Articles. i edited the post, thanks

Comment: That's because of `$prices`. Should be `$prices[$m]`

Comment: its getting to much complicated, this is why if there is any chance to restructure it all. i am doing that right now and i was thinking about getting an articles as array, so every article should have the first image and his own price. i am stuck where i dont know how to combine them together as a variable string (same as $images)

Comment: after changing $prices to $prices[$m] , i am getting it like (€Array EUR)

Comment: Should be `$prices[$i]` as you use `$i` in your loop.

Comment: $prices[$i] , gave the same first article price for all other articles.

Comment: You have only _one_ article with _one_ price and multiple images. So yeah, every image will give the same price.

Comment: ok i will edit the variable name so u got what i mean

Comment: after editing it, i need ($articlesss .= '<div ....) to bring me every article with his first image and his only price. can u maybe explain your idea in a code answer not only comment so i can understand you well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                            $m=0;
                            foreach($p->ARTICLEDATA->ARTICLE as $articless)
                            {
                                if($m==0)
                                {
                                    $price = (string) $articless->A_PRICEDATA->A_PRICE->A_VK;
                                    foreach($articless->A_MEDIADATA as $bild)
                                    {
                                        $firstImage = (string) $bild->A_MEDIA[2];
                                        $articles .= '<div class="photo"><img src="' . $firstImage . '" style="width: 120px margin:5px;"><div class="product-info mt__15"><h3 class="product-title pr fs__14 mg__0 fwm">' . $prod . '</h3><span class="price">€' . $price . ' EUR</span></div></div>';
                                    }
                                }
                            $m++;
                            }
```

Comment: i could finally achive it in this way. Thanks for all of you for all the Efforts. Until we meet again

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to keep track with counters and loops to tell if it is the first (index 0) entry.

Assuming all fields for the articles are present, you can use SimpleXML, loop all the article entries, and take the price (as there is only a single price) and first image per article using the index 0.

Then per entry, you can append the string with the variables to `$articles`

Note that `$produkt` is not present in the example code, so I have added a hardcoded value just for the example.

```
$articles = "";

foreach ($xml->ARTICLEDATA->ARTICLE as $article) {
    $price = (string)$article->A_PRICEDATA->A_PRICE->A_VK;
    $firstImage = (string)$article->A_MEDIADATA->A_MEDIA[0];
    $produkt = "Product 1";
    $articles .= '<div class="photo"><img src="' . $firstImage . '" style="width: 120px margin:5px;"><div class="product-info mt__15"><h3 class="product-title pr fs__14 mg__0 fwm">' . $produkt . '</h3><span class="price">€' . $price . ' EUR</span></div></div>';
}

echo $articles;
```

See a [PHP demo](https://3v4l.org/G5J6H)

Comment: First of all, Thank you very very much for your effort, this means alot. i just wanted to tell you that, when i am trying to move the Variable $articles outside the Foreach and make it just one line for the three cases that i have (Main Cat, Sub Cat, Product Cat) , it brings back only one photo and one price (even if choosing Main Cat as an example must return all the product that are relative to it). But when i write it the same as you did inside the foreach, it repeats every product image and infos for five time. do you have any idea why? thaaaanks

Comment: @MaherHaddad Which variable? If you place the variable outside of the foreach, and fill it inside the foreach, you will overwrite the variable each time, having the variable containing the value of the last iteration of the foreach.

Comment: i will expand the xml source and the php code maybe it will make difference, as long as you are here now you may figure it out immediatly. i am fresh graduated junior developer and still lose alot of time on such a small cases.

Comment: i hope that i could make it clear with the last edit

Comment: @MaherHaddad See this example https://3v4l.org/a5GT6

Comment: i have try to implement it many times, but didn't work as supposed to be, many articles are missing, and only few articles are duplicated. so maybe if there is away to send you the full code. i will upload the file it on my github and send you the link.

Comment: https://github.com/Miz-373/generator